# Injecting a custom response header in RESTEasy JAX-RS

Tags: web-services, http-headers, jax-rs, response, resteasy

I have RESTEasy (JAX-RS) server with about 60 services (so far). I would like to automatically inject a custom response header to provider callers with the server build time: `X-BuildTime: 20100335.1130`.

Is there an easy way to do this without modifying each of my services?

I am trying to use a class that implements `org.jboss.resteasy.spi.interception.PostProcessInterceptor` with annotations `@Provider` and `@ServerInterceptor`, but I can't figure out how to modify the ServerResponse that is passed into my `postProcess()` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think using `javax.servlet.Filter` will be a much easier solution:

```
public void doFilter ( ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain ) throws IOException, ServletException {
   HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;
   httpResponse.setHeadder(header, headerValue);
   chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

configure it in web.xml for the relevant urls, and you are done.

Answer (score 12):

Although `MessageBodyWriterInterceptor` does the trick, it is better to use `PostProcessInterceptor`, as it will intercept responses that do not call MessageBodyWriters (such as `Response.created(URI.create("/rest/justcreated")).build()`).

For more info, see the official [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.1.GA/userguide/html_single/#PostProcessInterceptors).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.interception.ServerInterceptor;
import org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponse;
import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.interception.PostProcessInterceptor;

@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
public class MyPostProcessInterceptor implements PostProcessInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void postProcess(ServerResponse response) {
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = response.getMetadata();
        List<Object> domains = headers.get("X-BuildTime");
        if (domains == null) { domains = new ArrayList<Object>(); }
        domains.add("20100335.1130");
        headers.put("X-BuildTime", domains);
    }

}
```

Comment: or if you just wanted to add/replace the header regardless of existing you could use: 
    response.getMetadata().putSingle("X-BuildTime", "20100335.1130");

Answer (score 4):

How about using javax.ws.rs.core.Response ; this way you can set the header in the same place where you create the response-data.

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response test(           ){
    HashMap<String,String> ret = new HashMap<String,String>();
    ret.put("foo","bar");
    return Response
       .status(Response.Status.OK)
       .entity(ret)
       .header("X-say", "Hello world!")
       .build();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also change header by [MessageBodyInterceptors](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.4.Final/userguide/html/Interceptors.html#MessageBodyInterceptors)

( check the example at the end of section 30.1 )

```
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
public class MyHeaderDecorator implements MessageBodyWriterInterceptor {

    public void write(MessageBodyWriterContext context) throws IOException, WebApplicationException
    {
       context.getHeaders().add("My-Header", "custom");
       context.proceed();
    }
}
```